# C I have a database project that hasn't been running due to the error "zsh: illegal hardware instructions ./main"

Tags: c, macos, malloc, zsh, file-handling

```
/* databaseLogic.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_STR_LEN = 20;

int roomAvailability(int roomChecked)
{
    FILE* fileAvailable;

    char filename[46];
    sprintf(filename, "../../databaseManagement/roomParent/room%d.txt", roomChecked);
    fileAvailable = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fileAvailable == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(fileAvailable);
}

int roomDataIn(char userData[10][MAX_STR_LEN], int roomRequested)
{
    FILE *openRoom;
    char dataInBuffer[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char filename[46];
    sprintf(filename, "../../databaseManagement/roomParent/room%d.txt", roomRequested);
    openRoom = fopen(filename, "r");
    fclose(openRoom);
    if(openRoom == NULL)
    {
        openRoom = fopen(filename, "w");
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            sprintf(dataInBuffer, "%s\n", userData[i]);
            fputs(dataInBuffer, openRoom);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not found");
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(openRoom);
    return 0;
}
char  *roomDataOut(int roomRequested, int requestedLine)
{
    
    FILE *openRoom;
    char filename[46];
    char *pulledData = (char *)malloc(MAX_STR_LEN*8);

    sprintf(filename, "../../databaseManagement/roomParent/room%d.txt", roomRequested);
    openRoom = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(openRoom != NULL)
    {
        
        char tempStorage[MAX_STR_LEN];
        for(int i=0;i<requestedLine-1;i++)
        {
            fgets(tempStorage, 20, openRoom);
        }
        fgets(pulledData, 20, openRoom);
        fclose(openRoom);
        return pulledData;
    }
    printf("failure");
    return "failure";
    
}
```

```
/* databaseLogic.h */

extern int roomDataIn(char *userData, int requestedRoom);

extern int roomAvailability(int requestedRoom);

extern char *roomDataOut(int requestedRoom, int requestedLine);
```

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "checkIn.h"
#include "checkOut.h"
#include "databaseLogic.h"
const char num1[2];

int main() 
{
    char test[10][10] = {"1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890", "1234567890"};
    printf("%d", roomAvailability(3));
    printf("%d", roomDataIn(*test, 3));
    printf("%s", roomDataOut(3, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

into the terminal i entered:

```
clang main.c checkIn.c checkOut.c databaseLogic.c -o main
./main
```

I was expecting it to detect that there isnt a file there using roomAvailability, create the file using roomDataIn, and then read from the file using roomDataOut but instead i got an error from terminal saying: "zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./main"

I only started getting this error after I started using malloc but it is necessary as I need the string to be passed back into main and cant if its volatile

Comment: Your `roomAvailability()` function returns before closing the file.

Comment: With `char filename[46];` are you 100% sure that the generated string will never be longer than 46 characters, *including* the null terminator? Why such little space, on a modern PC there's not really any need to be greedy, use `256` for the size. And use `snprintf` to make sure you don't go out of bounds of the string.

Comment: On another note: `sprintf(dataInBuffer, "%s\n", userData[i]); fputs(dataInBuffer, openRoom);`? Why not just use `fprintf(openRoom, "%s\n", userData[i]);`?

Comment: `char test[10][10] = {"1234567890",...` Are you aware that this array does not store valid C strings? There is not enough room to store the terminating 0 byte. This is generally valid in C. It just means, these are no strings and therefore you mustn't pass these arrays to any function expecting a string.

Comment: Your sprintf is dangerous. You don't have real control of how many characters are written to `filename`, as this depends on the value of `roomRequested`.  How can you know that 46 characters will be enough?